# Sending an email via python from my raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux, email, smtp, filepath

id like to send emails regularly from my raspberry pi with a small appended excel file. For this i use my a gmail account. I can send emails but not with something appended.

These following lines are faulty:
SendMail.prepareMail(…)
and
part.set_payload(os.open(file), "rb").read()) -> this is the error i get "IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/'
i hope you can help me with that

```
import sys, smtplib, os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formatdate
from email import encoders

class SendMail(object):
  mailadress = 'teststand@gmail.com'
  smtpserver = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
  username = 'xxx'
  password = 'xxx'

def send(self, files):
  # Gather information, prepare mail
  to = self.mailadress
  From = self.mailadress
  #Subject contains preview of filenames
  if len(files) <= 3: subjAdd = ','.join(files)
  if len(files) > 3: subjAdd = ','.join(files[:3]) + '...'
  subject = 'Dateiupload: ' + subjAdd
  msg = self.prepareMail(From, to, subject, files)

#Connect to server and send mail
  server = smtplib.SMTP(self.smtpserver)
  server.ehlo() #Has something to do with sending information
  server.starttls() # Use encrypted SSL mode
  server.ehlo() # To make starttls work
  server.login(self.username, self.password)
  failed = server.sendmail(From, to, msg.as_string())
  server.quit()

def prepareMail(self, From, to, subject, attachments):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = From
    msg['To'] = to
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

# The Body message is empty
msg.attach( MIMEText("") )

for file in attachments:
  #We could check for mimetypes here, but I'm too lazy
  part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
  part.set_payload( open(os.open(file),"rb").read() )
  Encoders.encode_base64(part)
  part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(file))
  msg.attach(part)
  #Delete created Tar
return msg

if __name__ == '__main__':
  mymail = SendMail()
  # Send all files included in command line arguments
  mymail.send(sys.argv[1:])

SendMail.prepareMail("teststand@gmail.com", "teststand@gmail.com", "empfanger@gmx.de", "Titel 1", "/home/pi/Desktop/Teststand/export/protokoll/Protokoll04_May_2020.xlsx")
```

Comment: The 'file' variable seems to be an directory, therefore you get this error message.

Comment: The 'file' variable is actually "/home/pi/Desktop/Teststand/export/protokoll/Protokoll04_May_2020.xlsx" as far as i can see its pointing to a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating through the variable attachments using the for loop, which is a string. So right now for file in attachment means file would contain every character in the string attachments.
Try:

```
SendMail.prepareMail("teststand@gmail.com", "teststand@gmail.com", "empfanger@gmx.de", "Titel 1", ["/home/pi/Desktop/Teststand/export/protokoll/Protokoll04_May_2020.xlsx"])
```

Pass the value of attachments in a list. So when you do for file in attachments, the value of file will be equal to the required location string.

Comment: this actual problem was solved but there seems to be an additional problem with error: 'str' object has no attribute 'mailadress'

Comment: Not exactly sure, try printing the values of to and From since they are referenced to mailaddress attribute